# How to scan, fix, and re-test

Tags: burp-suite

I'm a Burp newbie, but I've been working on it for several days now and still haven't come up with a satisfactory answer to this apparently simple problem. 
What I want to do seems quite straightforward:

1. Scan a site (automatically initially).
2. Fix one issue.
3. Repeat the single test/request that found the issue (or if necessary, repeat the whole scan), and have the response analysed so as to be assured that the issue is fixed.

I don't seem to be able to do this.

I ran an automated scan against my site, which found 4 vulnerabilities.
I then ran a second scan, with exactly the same settings, which found 0 vulnerabilities. I haven't changed anything, so why has it not found the same issues? 
(I've tried turning off "consolidate frequently occuring passive issues" with no effect)

I've copied a scan request which found an issue to the Repeater, and re-run it. The response is the same, but there is no analysis of the response to indicate whether or not there is still a vulnerability associated with the response.

In Site Map, if I delete an issue, then re-scan that endpoint, it doesn't find the issue again, even though it's not been fixed.

Comment: **Automatic scanners give automatic results.** Look at what the scanner claims to have found, then manually verify it. If necessary, patch it, then verify if the patch worked. The implication "The scanner does not find it, therefore it does not exist" is wrong.

Comment: Using a scanner without knowing how it works is like piloting a fighter jet while being a submarine commander. You will have an idea of what it is telling you, but no idea if that information is true or not, if it's concerning, informative, or critical.